# how to change a default django admin login view to generate token on login to admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

my site.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite


class OptiAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
        from core import views
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import views as contenttype_views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        #url(r'^$', wrap(self.index), name='index'),
        url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
      )
    return urlpatterns

opti_site = OptiAdminSite()
```

I'm developing an authentication API. When user logs in to my API it generates a code which get destroyed once user hit logout.

My problem is that whenever I'm running my API and django admin site in same browser, then if I login into admin-site It automatically login me in my API too with out any token. When I try to logout in that case from my API it generates an error - `'Token does not exist'`. I want to generate token when admin user login to admin-site.

I've tried to do it with above trick as in official documentation but didn't find the right way to do it.

Please suggest me the correct way to do it. Is it necessary to make a separate app for it?

Thanks! in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is almost complete... Almost, because you're simply creating your own admin site in `opti_site` variable, but probably not using it anywhere.

To make it work, you can monkey-patch default admin site with your site, using:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.sites.site = opti_site
admin.site = admin.sites.site
```

Remember that you must do it before root urlpatterns definition (especially before defining urls to your admin site).

Another approach is to change default admin to your admin in `include` of url patterns:

```
    url(r'^admin/', include(opti_site.urls)),
```